# how to set pdf file path to download the file from server

Tags: java, android, pdf, server

I want to download the pdf from my server, the path for the file I get from API response is like : E:\C1MS\REPORTS\003315150418.pdf

But, how can I download this file by giving my server's ip?

The path for server is : http://103.91.100.17:8080/creditOneFuelOneApp/

code to download the file

```
public static void DownloadFile(String fileURL, File directory) {
    try {

        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(directory);
        URL u = new URL(fileURL);
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();

        InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len1 = 0;
        while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
        }
        f.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

EDIT :

http://103.91.100.17:8080/creditOneFuelOneApp/statement

request

```
    {
"account_number" : "000584",
"user_type" : "C"
}
```

response

```
{
    "response_code": 0,
    "bill_due_date": "05-Jun-18",
    "last_bill_date": "01-Jun-18",
    "response_desc": "Success",
    "account_name": "Credit One",
    "last_bill_amount": "35083.00",
    "statement_list": [
        {
            "bill_amount": "35083.00",
            "file_location": "",
            "bill_date": "01-Jun-18",
            "due_date": "05-Jun-18"
        },
        {
            "bill_amount": "35083.00",
            "file_location": "E:\\C1MS\\REPORTS\\000584180501.pdf",
            "bill_date": "16-May-18",
            "due_date": "20-May-18"
        },
        {
            "bill_amount": "30083.00",
            "file_location": "E:\\C1MS\\REPORTS\\000584180401.pdf",
            "bill_date": "01-May-18",
            "due_date": "05-May-18"
        },
]
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: can't understand your question .. you want to download pdf from E drive ?

Comment: yes from that path.

Comment: is it your server  path ?

Comment: http://103.91.100.17:8080/creditOneFuelOneApp/ this is the path for the server and inside that in E drive the files are stored

Comment: then just append your ip address with `E:\C1MS\REPORTS\003315150418.pdf`  and its done

Comment: only ip address or whole path?

Comment: Ok you have a server. What kind of server is it? Which kind of script is used when you connect to the mentioned url? And that E: directory will contain more .pdf files. Who (and how)  is going to tell the server which file should be served?

Comment: it is a tomcat server, which stores some reports in E drive, and I get the path of the file by the API created in java. E drive has many files but we can give the file name which I am getting from api. @greenapps

Comment: Is creditOneFuelOneApp a directory? You should have told what you get if you use the url. Is a script used? You did not answer my question.

Comment: yes creditOneFuelOneApp a directory is a directory where it has api's, I use that url to access the api's. http://103.91.100.17:8080/creditOneFuelOneApp/statement this I use to get the response from api.

Comment: Please check edited question

Comment: How can a directory contain an api? Directories contain files. Is statement a file?

Comment: Put a pdf file in that directory and call it like `http://103.91.100.17:8080/creditOneFuelOneApp/003315150418.pdf`

Comment: that wont be a right path, shows page cant be find

Comment: Well if your Tomcat server cannot serve files... Why would that be a wrong path if it is a directory?

Comment: Did you write the statements yourself?

Comment: that file is in this path E:\\C1MS\\REPORTS\\000584180501.pdf. No I am getting the path from api. api's are written by other developers. they look into the server

Comment: Yes i know that that file is in that parh. But i asked you to put it in a different directory for a test. Now did you try it out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172936/discussion-between-sid-and-greenapps).

Answer (score 0):

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(path + File.separator
                                          + fileName));
```

Where your path is:

```
new StringBuilder("E:").append(File.separator)
                       .append("C1MS")
                       .append(File.separator)
                       .append("REPORTS").toString();
```

and file name: `"003315150418.pdf"`

Take a look to Oracle documentation [oracle fileupload](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html)

Comment: can we open this file from browser? what path we can give to access this file in browser? so the same path I can use for downloading right? also this file path has back slash and server path has front clash so it clashes, not getting the proper path.

Comment: Your servlet/controller will manage the upload process using `FileOutputStream`

Comment: and how can I download using FileOutputStream?

Comment: This is also a nonsense answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this .

```
String server_path = " http://103.91.100.17:8080/creditOneFuelOneApp/";
String server_location = "E:\C1MS\REPORTS\003315150418.pdf";
```

You can also dynamically generate your **server_location** String

now call your downloadFile function like this

**DownloadFile(server_path , server_location)**

```
public static void DownloadFile(String fileURL, File directory) {
    try {

        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(directory));
        URL u = new URL(fileURL);
      //YOUR OTHER CODE
    }

}
```

Comment: can we open this file from browser? what path we can give to access this file in browser? so the same path I can use  for downloading right? also this file path has back slash and server path has front clash so it clashes, not getting the proper path.

Comment: This is a nonsense answer.